# Spark does't run in Windows anymore

Tags: windows, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I have Windows 10 and I followed [this guide](https://medium.com/@GalarnykMichael/install-spark-on-windows-pyspark-4498a5d8d66c) to install Spark and make it work on my OS, as long as using Jupyter Notebook tool. I used this command to instantiate the master and import the packages I needed for my job:
`pyspark --packages graphframes:graphframes:0.8.1-spark3.0-s_2.12 --master local[2]`

However, later, I figured out that any worker wasn't instantiated according to the aforementioned guide and my tasks were really slow. Therefore, taking inspiration from [this](https://aamargajbhiye.medium.com/apache-spark-setup-a-multi-node-standalone-cluster-on-windows-63d413296971), since I could not find any other way to connect workers to the Cluster manager due to the fact it was run by Docker, I tried to set up everything manually with the following commands:
`bin\spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master`

The master was correctly instantiated, so I continued by the next command:
`bin\spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://<master_ip>:<port> --host <IP_ADDR>`
Which returned me the following error:

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
21/04/01 14:14:21 INFO Master: Started daemon with process name: 8168@DESKTOP-A7EPMQG
21/04/01 14:14:21 ERROR SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[main,5,main]
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.apache.spark.unsafe.array.ByteArrayMethods.<clinit>(ByteArrayMethods.java:54)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$.<init>(package.scala:1006)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$.<clinit>(package.scala)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.master.MasterArguments.<init>(MasterArguments.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master$.main(Master.scala:1123)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master.main(Master.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make private java.nio.DirectByteBuffer(long,int) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.nio" to unnamed module @60015ef5
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:357)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.checkCanSetAccessible(Constructor.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.setAccessible(Constructor.java:181)
        at org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform.<clinit>(Platform.java:56)
        ... 6 more
```

From that moment on, none of the commands I used to run before were working anymore, and they returned the message you can see. I guess I messed up some Java stuff, but I do not understand what and where, honestly.

My java version is:

```
java version "16" 2021-03-16
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 16+36-2231)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16+36-2231, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: Looks like a java version problem. What's your version?

Comment: I edited the OP with more information.

Comment: Java 16 is not supported by Spark. Use Java 8/11.

Comment: Indeed that was the problem, thank you.

Comment: It's not windows. It's Java 16 that has broken Spark.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I got the same error just now, the issue seems with Java version.

1. I installed java, python, spark etc. All latest versions... !
2. Followed steps mentioned in the below link..

https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-spark-on-windows-10

3. Got the same error as you.. !
4. Downloaded Java SE 8 version from Oracle site..

https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html

Downloaded jdk-8u281-windows-x64.exe

5. Reset the JAVA_HOME.
6. Started spark-shell   - it opened perfectly without any issues.

FYI: I don't have neither java or spark experience, if anyone feels something is wrong please correct me. Just that it worked for me, so providing the same solution here.. :)

Thanks,
Karun

Comment: Spark supports Java 11, so you should use that

Comment: You can even use openjdk, either version 8 or 11, alternatively tot the "official" java which requires to be registered!

Comment: It worked for me. I am using Spark 3.1.2, winutils 3.2.2 with java 8.

Answer (score 2):

I got a similar error on MacOS. The problem was with Java (I was using JDK 17), had to downgrade or use a different version.

Ended up using this:
https://adoptium.net/releases.html?variant=openjdk11
Download and install. Might have to remove your JDK17 version.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution :

Latest version of Java (JDK) is not supported by Spark.
Please try installing JDK version 8. This will solve the error.