# Trying to Run pyspark Mac

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, pip

I have been trying to get up and running for a college project for about two weeks now following any tutorial i could find online and i am getting the error below.

Error:

```
`@Mac-mini ~ % pyspark
Python 3.9.7 (default, Sep  3 2021, 12:37:55) 
[Clang 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.spark.unsafe.array.ByteArrayMethods.<clinit>(ByteArrayMethods.java:54)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$.<init>(package.scala:1095)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$.<clinit>(package.scala)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.$anonfun$loadEnvironmentArguments$3(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:157)
    at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:447)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.loadEnvironmentArguments(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:157)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.<init>(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2$$anon$3.<init>(SparkSubmit.scala:1022)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.parseArguments(SparkSubmit.scala:1022)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1039)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1048)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make private java.nio.DirectByteBuffer(long,int) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.nio" to unnamed module @24912924
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.checkCanSetAccessible(Constructor.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.setAccessible(Constructor.java:181)
    at org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform.<clinit>(Platform.java:56)
    ... 13 more
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/python/pyspark/shell.py", line 35, in <module>
    SparkContext._ensure_initialized()  # type: ignore
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 331, in _ensure_initialized
    SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/java_gateway.py", line 108, in launch_gateway
    raise Exception("Java gateway process exited before sending its port number")
Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number
```

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66904801/2129801). Although the question refers to Windows, the error message is the same. You could try to switch the Java version. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Answer (score 0):

Change `JAVA_HOME` to different Java version.

I had exactly the same error message while having `JAVA_HOME` set to `openjdk-16.0.1` path, then I changed it to `adoptopenjdk-12.jdk` path and the PySpark Exception: `Java gateway process exited before sending its port number` has gone.

Thanks @werner for suggestion.